# Can a hydrogen atom emit characteristic X-ray?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, collision, elementary-particles, x-rays

Is it not possible that incoming electron excite the hydrogen atom and then when it de-excites it releases radiation?
Here please don't answer no because hydrogen is light.
My actual query is can characteristic xray be produced by excitation and then deexcitation? Is knocking of electron necessary?

Comment: The nuclear charge of hydrogen is too small for hydrogen to emit x-rays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it not possible that incoming electron excite the hydrogen atom and then when it de-excites it releases radiation?

Yes, that is what is happening. It is a confluence of photons, and [it has frequencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Electromagnetic_spectrum) that start from gamma rays and end in very low frequency ELF. The spectrum of the hydrogen atom emitted photons that create radiation is in the visible frequencies.

> Here please don't answer no because hydrogen is light.

Well, do not use it as an exampe then. Its transitions do not have enoug energy to create X-rays.

> My actual query is can characteristic xray be produced by excitation and then deexcitation? Is knocking of electron necessary.

Yes, the X ray lines happen because an electron in an atom is changing energy levels. There are two ways to change energy levels in an atom: 1) absorb a photon and go to a higher energy level, 2 emit a photon and go to a lower energy level.

The *only* way to get *characteristic x* rays is in exciting the atoms, which then deexcite giving  the specific frequency.